# Find fundamental matrix in Floquet theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

I have problems finding the fundamental matrix for this exercise of Floquet theory
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= − \sin(2t)x + (\cos(2t) − 1)y\\
\dot{y} &= (\cos(2t) + 1)x + \sin(2t)y
\end{align*}

I noticed that if I rearrange this system into the form of $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ then $trace(A)=0$ and using the formula of the Wronskian I have
$$W(t)=1,$$
I think the matrix is something like
$$\Phi(t)=\begin{bmatrix} e^{t}\cos(2t) & -e^{-t}\sin(2t)\\
e^{t}\sin(2t) & e^{-t}\cos(2t)  \end{bmatrix},$$
but that matrix does not satisfy that
$$\dot{\Phi}(t)=A(t) \Phi(t).$$

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract common factors in both equations of the system to get
\begin{align}
\dot x &=-2\sin(t)(\cos(t)x+\sin(t)y)\\
\dot y &= 2\cos(t)(\cos(t)x+\sin(t)y)
\end{align}
The common factor $z=\cos(t)x+\sin(t)y$ has the derivative
\begin{align}
\dot z&=-\sin(t)x+\cos(t)y+\cos(t)\dot x+\sin(t)\dot y\\
&=-\sin(t)x+\cos(t)y=w\\
\ddot z=\dot w&=-z+2z=z
\end{align}
The solution can now be traced backwards.

Comment: Such an elegant proof. Many thanks!!